# What is the correct 'git-add' command to issue after running 'git-mergetool'?

Tags: git, git-merge, git-add

I'm unclear on the correct sequence of Git commands required to complete a merge that has resulted in conflicts. I understand that one approach is to follow the rejected merge with something like

```
git mergetool
# Then once everything has been fixed
git add ??
git commit -m "Some message"
```

but it isn't clear to me exactly what the `git-add` command should consist of in order to ensure that only the files I originally staged for the rejected merge are ultimately committed, and that only those files are committed.

Comment: Doesn't `mergetool` already do that based on the return status of the tool?  What happens if you `git merge --continue`?

Comment: @CarlNorum: I can't be sure that the tool is returning (I may not always know what tool has been used). Is there an approach that will work regardless of whether the tool's return status is useful?

Comment: Sorry - dunno.  It's always 'just worked' for me.  Hopefully someone will be along to help you out shortly.

Comment: `git-mergetool` will not stage the file if the mergetool returns non-zero. I'm not clear what exactly you want to to commit... After you do a merge, the automerged files will be staged, the conflicted files will prevent you from committing until they have been resolved.

Comment: @djs: Say, for example, I've got no uncommitted changes of my own, and then I've done a `git pull` resulting a merge that I need to complete manually. I then resolve all the collisions with `git mergetool` and want to commit what I've just done, but, need to stage that first. So the question is: how do I ensure I stage all those changes, and only those changes.

Comment: `git-mergetool` automatically stages if the mergetool returns exit code 0. In the scenario you describe, once `git-mergetool` returns, everything you want to commit will already be staged. So, I'm at a loss for what you're trying to do. If you made any further manual edits, those will not be staged unless you do a `git-add`.

Comment: @djs: Yes, that's the point (see my earlier comment in response to CarlNorum): I can't be sure what the the mergetool will return, so I'm looking for something that will work even if it doesn't return something informative. Alternatively, is there a list somewhere of mergtools that do/don't return a trustworthy exit code?

Comment: I still don't understand what you're trying to get at :) However, I do understand the point about bogus exit codes from merge tools. I recommend p4merge or kdiff3, which are compliant. See the git option mergetool.<tool>.trustExitCode to work with a tool that doesn't return the proper exit code.

Comment: @djs: So if I use p4merge or kdiff3, and set trustExitCode to true I can just commit without bothering to add? If so, that's an answer. (Though what threw me in the first place is that all the examples I've seen online for configuring these tools shoe trustExitCode explicitly set to false.)

Comment: no, p4merge at least does not set the correct exit code – git checks whether the file has changed or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`git-mergetool` will normally automatically stage files after the conflicts have been resolved. You will not need to manually run `git-add`.

However, in order to work with a variety of tools, `git-mergetool` will try to verify that the file has been updated (see [check_unchanged()](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/git-mergetool--lib.sh)) by checking the modification date. If the file has been modified, then, it will check the return code from the mergetool.

Some mergetools may not return the correct exit code (0 if the merge 'succeeded'), and so git also provides a configuration option `mergetool.<tool>.trustExitCode` in case this should not be trusted. If this is set to `false`, then git will always ask you if the merge was successful.

In summary:

1. Your mergetool should save the file to disk after merging, even if no changes are necessary (which shouldn't be possible, since it wouldn't be a merge conflict).
2. If you don't trust the exit code of your mergetool, you can set the `trustExitCode` option to false.

In practice, I recommend using one of the merge utilities that git now natively supports. You can get a list of these [here](https://github.com/git/git/tree/master/mergetools). If you use one of these tools, you should not need any additional setup beyond configuring git to use it, e.g.:

```
git config --global merge.tool p4merge
```

**Note:** You may find a lot of outdated articles around the web about setup for these tools. My favorite mergetool, [p4merge](http://www.perforce.com/product/components/perforce_visual_merge_and_diff_tools), for example, was not natively supported by git at first, and required some manual configuration. This is no longer necessary for recent versions of git.

Comment: This looks right: if I use p4merge then the merged files are staged after exiting and I just need to do a commit; no need for an add. But I have two questions: (1) What does "git will always ask you if the merge was successful" mean? I have `trustExitCode set` to `false`, but don't get "asked" anything after I exit p4merge. (2) What would happen if I set `trustExitCode set` to `true`? (3) @Chronial says (in a comment to the question) that p4merge does not set the correct exit code. Does that mean I should set (as I have) `trustExitCode set` to `false`?

Comment: And a note on your note: p4merge still seems to require a path specification with, for example, `git config --global mergetool.p4merge.path <path to p4merge shell executable>` (e.g., on a Mac: "/Applications/p4merge.app/Contents/MacOS/p4merge").

Comment: Yes, it requires it to be in your path, or to explicitly set the path. I generally add p4merge to my system PATH on Windows.

Comment: Since p4merge is supported, you don't need to worry about this. The custom configuration included for p4merge will verify that the file was changed instead of depending on the exit code. So, in this case trustExitCode makes no difference. See the source for [p4merge](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/mergetools/p4merge). To test: try doing a merge and then save the file in p4merge. It won't prompt you. If you close without saving, it will prompt you.